# Core Data creating NSPredicate for NSNumber using something akin to BEGINSWITH

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to retrieve results from search bar text in Core Data on a property that is an NSNumber.
In particular, getting objects from the store whose id number "BEGINSWITH" the search text.

As an example, if the user enters the number "1" in the search box, my fetched request returns objects including 1, 12, 14, 19, 100, 149, 1324, etc.

Unfortunately, I am implementing sorting on the table as well, so when sorting by this id number, if represented as a string in the data model, sorting becomes: 1,10,100,2,20,200 instead of 1,2,10,20,100,200.

How can I go about getting the best of both worlds here such that I can search in a string-sort-of-way but sort in a number-sort-of-way?
Do I have to create two properties in the data model, a string and a number representation of the same data?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Rgds,
Felipe

Comment: I resolved my own issue. Instead of converting the search string to an int and using BEGINSWITH with the id number on the left and the search int on the right, I was able to use BEGINSWITH with the id number on the left and the search string on the right. Both searching and sorting work great.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Turns out this did not solve my issue...I am still unable to to sort on NSNumbers using BEGINSWITH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have two fields, the actual identifier that is a number and then a searchIdentifier which is a string.  Search on the string, sort on the number.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not mentioned anywhere in the apple documentation, Like works with nsnumber as well.

For example,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"numberField like '%@*'", searchTerm]
```

works, where numberField is a core data attribute of type NSNumber. This fetches all records where numberfield value begins with searchTerm.